# Migrate database from Enterprise to Community Edition

Tags: magento-enterprise, database, migration

I'm in the process of downgrade from Enterprise 1.14 to Community.
I have seen this post http://www.yanted.com/2014/02/21/downgrading-magento-enterprise-to-community/

What I want to do is do a fresh install of Magento Community (latest version) and use my old database from enterprise but fix it to can use it with community.

So, should I delete all the tables that start with the prefix enterprise? And also do what says in the post

> DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE source_model LIKE 'enterprise_%';
>
> DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE backend_model LIKE 'enterprise_%';
>
> DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code IN ('gift_wrapping_available', 'gift_wrapping_price');

I want to do it the cleanest but need to preserve the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion it's much easier to export the Customers, Orders, Products, and Attributes and just re upload them into the new instance with a .CSV. You can use the dataflow and/or Magmi.

Customers - Dataflow (Default magento)

Products - http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Attributes and Attribute Sets - http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Import_Attributes_%26_Attribute_Sets 
Addon for Magmi

Orders - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673529/magento-order-import-export
I use this, it's paid. Just easier. However, if you need to do an import, there is other PHP scripts online for this as well.

Run Index once you have your DNS, Magento Installation, and New DB Setup and Indexing should fix you URLs as well.

For Modules, that can be a little harder and you would have to fight that 1 battle at a time as you are likely to run into a lot of conflicts.

Best of Luck!

Comment: At the end that's what I had to do. I did a fresh installation with the community and export all the old data to the new database. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help.   Best of luck in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I did a downgrade a few months back from EE 1.12 to CE 1.9
Biggest job was to convert all the templates, moving away from the enterprise version of said files.

Great time to do a revamp of site skin, if a revamp is potentially intended later. The bulk of the work was to fix templates, and move away from the enterprise versions. It will save time to do that at the same time (potentially)

Also, remember that the password encryption between CE and EE is not compatible. Search stack for answers to this, there are solutions.

See my blog entry here: http://www.proxiblue.com.au/blog/downgrade-ee-to-ce/ , where I noted my path to downgrade, and there is also a gist with a script that did some cleanup, including db changes. (if I recall based of that same article you noted)

Ultimately, your best tool is TEST TEST TEST TEST - not by you, but by other users!

Comment: I really really I tried to do this without any luck. It didn't load anything with my old database.  I assumed it was because it has some bad data. But thank you.